# How to customize the rendering of the straight lines in mode line?

Tags: faces, mode-line, rendering, customize-face

Here are two examples of what I mean:

1. The lines are rendered in a different color as the background, so they are clearly seen:
   [image]
2. The lines are rendered in the same color as the background, so they can not be seen:
   [image]

So, I would like to know how to tweak that, probably setting a face attribute.
Whether to render it clearly or hide it.

Comment: See the `:box` attribute:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html  `M-x customize-face`  for both `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`  [The question is likely a duplicate of something from somewhere, but I don't have time to search/Google right now ...]

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. Wrote the answer, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Following @lawlist advise, using `:box` attribute for `mode-line-inactive` made it.

The mode lines images shown in the question are from inactive frames.
The second image shows an inactive frame with a mode line that does not render the straight lines.

Using:

```
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive nil :box t)
```

renders the straight line with foreground color:

[image]

as it is indicated in [Face Attributes section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html) of Emacs Lisp manual.